# how to extract from two delimiter

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
1+2+3:4+5+6:7+8+9
```

How to delimit if i have two delimiter + and :
and i am using array to store

```
myarray1 = [myarray2 componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]; delimit only :
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *myString = @"Foo-bar/blee";
NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                      [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-/"]
                    ];
```

Comment: In your case the delimiters would be @"+:"